# man <whatever> opens vim with hidden characters displayed

Tags: macos, vim, gvim, man

I'm on Mac/Sierra using MacVim. When I run man  MacVim (I have alias vim="mvim" set in my .bashrc) I get the man page with hidden whitepace characters displayed.

This only happens for man pages (I don't have any vim settings set to display hidden characters).

For example, **`man ls`** gives:

[image]

Any tips on how to remedy? It's readable, but annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man` calls a program defined as pager. On OS X it uses the one defined in `PAGER` environment variable.

Use:

```
export PAGER=less
```

to set it to `less`.

You should also look in your rc-scripts to find the line that sets it to `vim` and correct it.

Comment: Bingo---Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!